# PATH environment variable in Linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I want to know how the standard environment variables given by the Linux OS like PATH, HOME are set automatically. Which file(s) are these read from. There should be some file from which these variables are set when a particular user logs in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to add a few more details to what @cnicutar has already mentioned.

Environment variables including `PATH` can be:

- System wide - The values of the environment variables last till the system is up
- Session wide - Lasts till a session lasts (till user logs out)

`/etc/profile` is meant for system settings for Bourne & Bourne compatible shells. The behavior of `/etc/profile` *may* vary across distributions.

For the latest Ubuntu distributions, it is recommended to use `/etc/environment` for system-wide settings. It is **not recommended** to use `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` as noted the [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables).

On Ubuntu machines, `/etc/profile` is a shell script which sources the scripts in `/etc/profile.d` and the system-wide `bashrc` file in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, whereas `/etc/environment` is a text file consisting of variable assignments per line which are set into the system-wide environment.

For each user the values of environment variables including `PATH` (for the shell) can also be manipulated through `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~./bash_login`, and `~/.bashrc` where `~` means the user's home directory, like `/home/alex/`.

To see your current environment variables and their values, you can use [`printenv`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printenv.1.html).

You can refer to the following link for more details on environment variables on Ubuntu systems: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: The link given here 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

now suggest to change in /etc/environment instead of /etc/profile. It states changing in /etc/profile is not recommended anymore. 

and you have to restart or x restart to make it work.

Comment: @VampireCoder: Thanks! I have updated the response. Please feel free to edit to update/make the response better

Comment: After changing /etc/environment, it would be great if we do source /etc/environment

Comment: @AmitPandya: Sure `source` or `.` or equivalent *could* work but AFAIK it would be only for that shell wherein you invoke it. The purpose of `/etc/environment` AFAIK in for system wide setting so a better option probably would be log out - log in.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing magic about them, the shell sets them when it starts up.

You should start reading `/etc/profile` and work up from there. Alternatively, `strace` might show you what files the shell tries to read when it starts.

For instance, here is how my `/etc/profile` starts:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH
```

After that is sources other files which in their turn modify `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You can even set and manage your environment variables by yourself by using module enviroment software [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Modules_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Modules_%28software%29).
To install *"module"* you can use this command for Centos

```
sudo yum install environment-modules
```

For Ubuntu users, you can install it from source:
http://modules.sourceforge.net/

Write a module file to set or prepend environment variables. Then you modules to load this file.
For example, my files name "mypath"

```
proc ModulesHelp { } {
global version prefix

puts stderr "\t Loads the environment for my installed home folder HOME/local"
}

module-whatis   "Loads the environment for my installed home folder HOME/local"

set     HOME    /home/svu/a0081742

prepend-path    PATH            $HOME/local/bin
prepend-path    LIBRARY_PATH    $HOME/local/lib
prepend-path    LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/local/lib
prepend-path    LD_INCLUDE_PATH $HOME/local/include
prepend-path    MANPATH         $HOME/local/share/man
```

Then, you load the file with

```
module load mypath
```

Than you can list your loaded modules with

```
module list
```