# Environment variable PATH on linux

Tags: linux, debian, environment-variables

Hi i am currently trying to set keywords for my terminal to launch some software without having to type the whole path.
For exemple:

```
firefox
#instead of
/home/debian/firefox/firefox
```

I always do this kind of thing on windows by setting path in the environment variable manager.
After i read this post [PATH environment variable in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510249/path-environment-variable-in-linux) , i added this line to the etc/environment file:

```
export firefox=/home/debian/firefox/firefox
#I also tried this:
export PATH=$PATH:/home/debian/firefox
```

It doesn't work, can someone explains me how to do this?

Comment: What does it do? What's the `$PATH` variable after you export this? Did you open a new shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would setup a new alias in my `.bashrc` or `.profile`, which should be located under your home directory. Add the following to the end of the file:

```
alias firefox="/home/debian/firefox/firefox"
```

Save the file and reload it using:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Since you added the alias to your `.bashrc` this alias will be created everytime you open a new instance of a shell.

You could use `nohup` to keep the command running after the shell session ends:

```
alias firefox="nohup /home/debian/firefox/firefox &"
```

Notice the trailing `&` character, which will run the command in the background so you can keep using your terminal.

Comment: It works but it locks the terminal as if it where running a compiler or something like that. I would like to just launch my software and then get the hand over my terminal again while my software runs in X window.
If i < ctr-c> i can use my terminal again but the software get shut down.

Comment: @aurelienC - Have you tried using `nohup` as in my above example?

Comment: The terminal is still unusable after i launch firefox. Of course i can close my terminal and firefox keeps on running but my aim is to launch things on the fly when i am using the terminal and keep using it after.

Comment: @aurelienC - Have you really tried appending the `&` character to the end: `alias firefox="nohup /home/debian/firefox/firefox &"`? This works just fine for me anyway?

Comment: Nevermind, it works for me too i forgot to recompile (or what ever it is) with source.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make an alias in your `.bashrc` file.

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

It will open your `.bashrc` in read mode. Get in write mode by pressing `i`. You can create alias at anywhere in the file or below already created alias list.

```
alias firefox='/home/debian/firefox/firefox'
```

press `Esc` and then `:wq`
This will create your alias, save and exit the file. Now you only have to compile `.bashrc` by this

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

After this you can only have to use `firefox` instead of long `/home/debian/firefox/firefox`

Answer (score 1):

Adding `/home/debian/firefox` to your `PATH` should have done it.

Did you start a new shell after making that change? Otherwise the new `PATH` would not have exported yet. Alternatively, you can just run `export PATH=$PATH:/home/debian/firefox` directly to update it for your current session.