# Why my java version in terminal is different from the jdk version showed in idea?

Tags: java, macos

My java version in terminal is different from the version in IntelliJ.

When I typed 'java -version' in the terminal, the version is 13.0.2, but when I set the SDK in the IntelliJ IDEA, the version is 11.0.4. I typed ' usr/libexec/java_home' in the terminal, but get the result 'zsh: no such file or directory: usr/libexec/java_home'. How should I fix it?

Comment: Try with below StackOverFlow question and answer. [Intellij IDEA terminal shows wrong jVM version with ./gradlew -version or mvn -version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167299/intellij-idea-terminal-shows-wrong-jvm-version-with-gradlew-version-or-mvn-v)

Comment: Please CHeck Below Answer [Intellij IDEA terminal shows wrong jVM version with ./gradlew -version or mvn -version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167299/intellij-idea-terminal-shows-wrong-jvm-version-with-gradlew-version-or-mvn-v)

Comment: Please refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167299/intellij-idea-terminal-shows-wrong-jvm-version-with-gradlew-version-or-mvn-v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```bash
$ java -version
```

will use the first `java` executable from your [PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510249/path-environment-variable-in-linux) variable. For example:

```bash
$ which java
/opt/dev/jdk/8/bin/java
```

IntelliJ IDEA uses JDK defined in settings. You can update it in `Project Structure`
[image]

> I typed ' usr/libexec/java_home' in the terminal, but get the result 'zsh: no such file or directory: usr/libexec/java_home'. How should I fix it?

Try this one instead:

```bash
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Comment: If this didn't work, please check in File -> Settings-> Tools -> Terminal in the idea

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File -> Project Structure -> Project` and set SDK to correct version. You can find path to it by executing

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is happened due to multiple jdk version existence in a local machine. To tackle this, need to set up the environment variable for our ease. There are couple of ways to switch it. This link will give you an understanding. Also do the same approach for your OS. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-multiple-jdks-in-windows/. Always need to address the foundations rather than making instant solutions.